# Авто воспроизведение видео на странице

Tags: javascript, html5

Подскажите как реализовать авто воспроизведение видео после загрузки страницы?
Знаю, что можно у тега `<video>` добавить атрибуты `autoplay` и `muted`. Но тогда оно будет воспроизводится без звука. Также знаю, что можно обойти это ограничение запустив например Google Chrome с параметром --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required.
Но как это реализовано например на ютубе? Вот пример: https://www.youtube.com/@CodePioneers/featured

При открытии ссылки начинается видео со звуком.

Comment: Со звуком воспроизводится только у "доверенных", таких как ютуб, который не воспроизводит помойку спама в уши. Так что со звуком не получится.... и я, как пользователь, сразу бы покинул такую площадку. Особенно если у меня колонки на 100 ватт включены

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а есть какая-нибудь статья/описание этого или ещё что-нибудь? По поводу того, что это плохая практика я полностью согласен, но есть задачи в которых это нужно. Как пример информационное табло электронной очереди, когда надо озвучивать вызов талона или рекламный ролик. Т.е. очень удобно добавить страничку в автозагрузку и не париться по поводу того, что после перезагрузки звука не будет.

Comment: *"или рекламный ролик."* --- вот против таких людей, которые включают рекламные ролики автоматом, да ещё и на полную громкость, и в введено ограничение.............. а в целом, проще и, наверное, корректнее, для электронной очереди сделать standalone приложение, а не web

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а PWA, можно считать за standalone? Не уверен, но там подобные ограничения вроде как обходятся.

Comment: @Neverm1ndo скажу проще. То, что запускается в браузере, использовать на информационном экране организации - очень странно и  бессмысленно

Answer (score 0):

Да действительно есть "белые списки" и тогда авто воспроизведение со звуком работает.
"Если сайт внесен в белый список; это может произойти либо автоматически, если браузер определяет, что пользователь часто взаимодействует с мультимедиа, либо вручную через настройки или другие функции пользовательского интерфейса."

Более подробно описано здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability

Comment: Ещё можно через политики браузера внести сайт в белый список.